# How to fix multiple SDK path warning in flutter project

Tags: android, flutter

I change sdk file then when i run the project it shows this error

```
Warning! The 'flutter' tool you are currently running is from a different Flutter repository than the one last used by this package. The repository from which the 'flutter' tool is currently executing will be used instead.
  running Flutter tool: C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\flutter
  previous reference  : C:\src\flutter
This can happen when you have multiple copies of flutter installed. Please check your system path to verify that you are running the expected version (run 'flutter --version' to see which flutter is on your path).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure you specified the correct path** i think in your case it's in desktop,but i suggest move it from desktop but it's your call or extract freshly somewhere else safe then specify that path , or you can specify correct path globally with set up Environment variables

**In Android Studio: Menu > File > Settings... > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter > Flutter SDK path: (change your path: C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\flutter)**

**Setup Flutter path globally with Environment variable**

1. open start menu and type `env`
2. open Edit the system environment variables
3. click on Environment Variables
4. under System variables, select Path then click Edit
5. click New then paste this line `C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\flutter\bin`
6. Press Ok,then restart the computer not necessary but just in case

**Notice:** Make sure you have correct path

After that run flutter clean then run flutter doctor,it will returns some details,when everything is marked then it's good to go

Comment: where can i run flutter clean because in terminal in android studio show me this :
**'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**
@Assassin

Comment: you need to setup flutter installation path in `Environment Variable` in windows @LailaMattar

Comment: I have updated  the answer follow the steps@LailaMattar

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error it is a warning which reminds you that you have currently two version of flutter SDK. If you don't need the old version you can delete it and the warning disappears (Don't forget to update your system path). Otherwise, as the warning said, make sure you are running the expected version by checking your system path.

Comment: when i delete the old version the project gets errors every where
@R.Shpq

Comment: Did you update your system path? and also specify the correct SDK path in your project setting. @LailaMattar